# In werewolv.es does the Ring of Tenacity cancel out the Disruption Orb if both items are held by the same player?

Tags: werewolv.es

The Ring of Tenacity states:

> The Ring of Tenacity prevents its bearer from being Roleblocked.

Whilst the Disruption says:

> A Disruption Orb will roleblock anyone visiting you that is not Night Immune. Unfortunately it will also roleblock you at the same time.

Since the Ring of Tenacity doesn't make someone night immune, will they still be role-blocked whilst holding the Disruption Orb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ring of Tenacity will win over the Orb's role-blocking here.

This is because the Ring of Tenacity adds an aura (visible to the Aura Seer) to its owner that gives them role block immunity which is active all the time. The Disruption Orb resolves at the end of the night phase and attempts to role-block its owner and everyone visiting its owner. The role-block is the same used by the Direwolf and Courtesan and includes the normal checks to bounce if the target is immune to role-blocks.

There discrepancy in the wording of the Orb's description because when it was made, the only protection against role-blocks was night immunity. That changed when the Ring of Tenacity and Potion of Resilience were made, and an additional property to players was added `ImmuneToRoleBlocks`. Existing night immune roles (such as the Vampire) had role-block immunity carried over when this change was made.

Comment: Follow-up question: does the Orb of Disruption block the holder every night, regardless of whether they are visited or not, or does it only block the holder if they are visited?